# Printer Quality in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, printing

Please anyone help me, i want to get the ***printer quality*** of laserjet printer which is installed using Bonjour in **MAC OS**. I already get the printer status of other type of printers by reading PPD file, but in the case of laserjet printers there is no print quality in PPD file. Is anyone have an idea about this please help me, Is it is possible using SNMP?